# Cross product equation with sine, I don't understand the unit vector "n"

Tags: vectors

$\vec{a} \times \vec{b}=\mid \vec{a} \mid \mid \vec{b} \mid \sin(\theta)\, \vec{n}$

I know this is probably an incredibly simple question, and I know that "n" is the unit vector at right angles to both equations, and that a unit vector has a magnitude of 1, its just for the purposes of this equation, I just don't understand how to find it for two given vectors.

I'm used to calculating the cross product by multiplying the numbers e.g. $i-j+k$, and I just found out that I need to learn this equation. This post must seem really rambly and unrefined, but I just can't find a conclusive answer, and I'm really desperate for some clarification.

Comment: There is no equation.

Comment: @CaptainLama - probably something like $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} = \left\| \mathbf{a} \right\| \left\| \mathbf{b} \right\| \sin \theta \ \mathbf{n}$ [(from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition)

Comment: You are asking how to find the unit vector $\hat n$ given vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. The equation with $\sin\theta$ can help you to find $\theta$ once you know the cross product, its magnitude, and the magnitudes (or norms) of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, but it won't help you find the direction vector $\hat n$. For that, just rescale the cross product to a unit vector. See my answer for elaboration.

Comment: @bgins Oh I see, so the equation is used to find theta already knowing the cross product, rather than the cross product knowing theta and n (which as I understand it know requires knowledge of the cross product in the first place). If this is the case, that really clarifies things. My lecture notes where really vague and 'maths is fun' and other places also gave a really vague explaination.

Comment: Any equation can be used to solve for any single variable (or quantity) occurring in it, given the others, if the variable can be isolated to a computable formula. In this formula, the solvable quantities would be the cross product $\vec a\times\vec b$, the norms of $\vec a$ & $\vec b $, $\theta$ or its sine, and $\hat n$. It is often a good exercise to try out examples with every new equation you encounter. Although vector equations are actually systems of equations in their coordinates, e.g. $\vec a\cdot\vec x=\vec a\cdot\vec x_0$, the plane through $\vec x_0$ normal to $\vec a$.

Comment: @bgins Right but I mean if I have understood it correctly it would be meaningless to solve for cross product given magnitude and theta as to know n one would already need to know cross product right?

Comment: @frostedcake Yes, true. You'd probably be better off using the right hand rule than this equation to find $\hat n$ (for an approximate geometric solution), or taking ${\vec n\over\lVert\vec n\rVert$ if you already knew $\vec n=\vec a\times\vec b$. The above equation is most useful to find the angle or, if known, the magnitude of the cross product (given those of its terms). I think you are understanding fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two curves $\vec x(t),\vec y(t):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$, the unit normal vector to them at some point $t$ is $$\hat n=\widehat{\vec x\times\vec y}=\frac{\vec x\times\vec y}{\lVert\vec x\times\vec y\rVert}=\frac{\vec x\times\vec y}{\lVert\vec x\rVert\cdot\lVert\vec y\rVert\cdot\sin\theta}=\frac{{\hat x}\times{\hat y}}{\sin\theta},$$
where $\theta$ is the angle of incidence between $\vec x$ & $\vec y$ and the "hat" (`^`) represents the unit version of any vector:
$$\vec x=(x_2,x_2,x_3)\implies\hat x=\frac{\vec x}{\lVert\vec x\rVert}=\frac{(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}.$$
So in your case (with your clarification),

> $$\hat n=\frac{\vec a\times\vec b}{\lVert \vec a\times\vec b \rVert}.$$

First find the cross product $\vec a\times\vec b$ in the numerator; then take its norm, to get the denominator. Then divide by that norm (a scalar multiplication) to get the unit version of $\vec a\times\vec b$. You can then calculate the angle $\theta$, if you need it, from
$$\vec a\times\vec b=\left(\lVert\vec a\rVert\cdot\lVert\vec b\rVert\cdot\sin\theta\right)\hat n$$
by taking the inverse sine of
$$\sin\theta=\frac{\lVert\vec a\times\vec b\rVert}{\lVert\vec a\rVert\cdot\lVert\vec b\rVert}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have the coordinates of two vectors and all you need to do is find the coordinates of their cross product, it would be silly to use the "$\sin\theta$" equation to find the answer. It is much simpler to add products
of the coordinates in the way you already know.

But knowing that
$$
\mathbf a \times \mathbf b
= \lVert \mathbf a \rVert \lVert \mathbf b \rVert (\sin\theta) \mathbf n,
$$
where $\mathbf n$ is a unit vector perpendicular to both $\mathbf a$
and $\mathbf b$, you can find the angle $\theta$ between two vectors
(given by their coordinates) by computing the cross-product without
using the "$\sin\theta$" formula, then plugging that result into
the equation above, taking the magnitude of both sides (which means
$\mathbf n$ drops out, since $\lVert\mathbf n\rVert = 1$), 
and solving for $\theta$.
(Of course, to find $\theta$ uniquely you must have some other information,
since there are generally two values of $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$
that both yield the same value of $\sin\theta$.)

On the other hand, if you happen to be given the magnitudes of two
vectors and the angle between them, you can immediately apply the
equation above without having to figure out how to convert the
magnitudes and angle into suitable coordinates of the two vectors.

So the equation does not always have to be used the same way.
It is simply one of several useful facts that can help you find out 
something about two vectors when you know some other things about them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Chill it with the "apparently". I think I get it now.

Comment: Sorry, that was _not_ meant as criticism, doubt, or sarcasm of any sort--it merely meant I was using information from the question. But on review, that word seems a bit ambiguous and unnecessary in context, so it's gone now.

Comment: Sorry I guess I overreacted, its just around these sites a lot people are really condescending. Thank you for your help it was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You know how to find the cross product, but you don't know how to normalize the vector?

If $\mathbf v = x\mathbf i+y\mathbf j+z\mathbf k$ then $||\mathbf v|| = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$, and you are looking for $\dfrac {\mathbf v}{||\mathbf v||}.$